# Rspec 2 config :type types

Tags: configuration, devise, helper, rspec2

In my spec_helper.rb I have

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

so that I can actually test my controllers that require the user to be authenticated. However, the spec for the same class in requests needs to sign in as well or the tests will fail. I've tried

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :request
```

but that doesn't work either. I cannot seem to find what type options I can pass into the rspec include or extend methods. I assume :model and :view would be there but the others I'm completely unsure of. What should I be using so my requests spec can pass and is there a list of the different types for :type?

Comment: I have the same question. Ever figure it out?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This commit should help clarify the `:type` option.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/commit/fc5cdbb603f0e66f9f3d19a0a60a775e124fb218

`:type => :request` is valid, so I'm unsure why your tests are failing.

Which directory holds your integration tests? Typically, they're located in `spec/requests` or possibly `spec/integration`.

You can use another option to specify when to include Devise::TestHelpers; the option is `:example_group`:

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :example_group => {
  :file_path => config.escaped_path(%w[spec (requests|integration)])
}
```

Now, Devise::TestHelpers will be included into example groups whose file is within the specified paths.

Make sure to replace the array member `(requests|integration)` with the folder name where your integration tests are located.

Comment: Excellent. This will help include a macros file for the new spec/features directory that Capybara 2.x likes to use.

Comment: config.escape_path does not work in the latest rspec I've used   `config.include RakeTestHelper, :example_group => { :file_path => %r(spec/api) }`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe is too late, but for anyone who needs it, changing the type to `:feature` worked for me:

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :feature
```